# Using created objects throughout a class

Tags: c#, object, methods

Alright. I'll try to present my problem in an organized manner.

What I'm working on is a weather map showing application. Nothing large, just something to create to gain a better understanding of programming. I have a working prototype, and I was excited about it, so I wondered if I could make it more organized and professional.

I'm trying to use a `struct` to use as a blueprint for a "State" object.
I have several fields within the struct to assign "properties" to the object.

I.E.

`State Louisiana = new State();
Louisiana.name = "Louisiana";`

Now, this is great. It does what I want. However, I'm running into issues understanding how to use it properly. **I have a method, called StateInitialization() that creates 50 instances of the struct, one for each state. However, outside of that method I cannot use, or even access, the State instances created, nor the properties.**

I would like to be able to do something like `Louisiana.SetIDInfo("LA", "Louisiana", 32);` in a different method of the same class. Or, I'd like to be able to set a variable in a method equal to one of the properties of the object: `string MyString = Louisiana.name;` Is that not possible, or am I misunderstanding something severely?

The article that I used as a reference for building my struct is [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_struct.htm).

A link to the abstracted struct code is [here](http://paste.ofcode.org/5mSLuV3mAagarY9M2jAjeV).
A link to the StateInitialization() method is [here](http://paste.ofcode.org/DbL3JQjtJxs4EYuN5WumgT).

The code that I have linked works perfectly properly. The problem is what I outlined in bold.

I think maybe some of the uses of "static" may be unnecessary or wrong. I'm not sure, to be honest. That's why I'm asking for help. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you show us some more of your code?
Why did you choose to use a struct and not a class?

Comment: Read about the [**scope**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29) of variables. Basically, they only live between the `{}` in which it was declared.

Comment: @SaverioTerracciano I chose a struct because it seemed to be what I needed; a way to create something and give it properties. I know you can access those variables in the same way if used in a class, but I didn't know how to go about creating properties of a class!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, a word about `struct`. In general, structures should contain nothing but data, and are immutable. You don't have to implement them that way, but the general practice is to use a `class` when you what to execute instance methods on them.

**Rule of thumb:** Use `class` not `struct`. Only use `struct` when you know *why* you want to do so.

However, that isn't what is breaking your sample. At the very bottom of your generation function you have:

```
State[] USA = new State[] { .... };
```

Which does what you would think, it creates a collection of states. However, that line declares a *new* variable, which means that it is scoped to the function. Code outside of that function is unaware of its existence. In fact, after the last line of the function executes, the local variables are said to be "out of scope" and will be garbage collected. If instead you wrote:

```
static State[] USA;

static void GenerateStates()
{
     ...
     USA = new State[] { ..... };
}
```

All other methods in your class would have access to the USA array. Note that this is a bit dangerous, because you could try to use it before GenerateStates is called, but I digress.

You also lost all your local variables (like `Louisiana`) so you won't be able to access them directly unless you declare *them* to be class level variables also. Alternatively, you could search the array for a state called "Louisiana" and try to use it:

```
USA.First(s => s.name == "Louisiana").SomeMethod();
```

Again, there are lots of other ways to accomplish this (a dictionary instead of an array comes to mind). This method will throw an exception if such a state does not exist, just to warn you.

You also asked about static. In standard console apps it is used a lot, but once you get out of that realm, you will generally not be using it. `static` allows you to use a class without having an instance of it (it uses the global "static" instance). Good OOP generally discourages this practice, but you shouldn't have to worry about it for while.

Comment: That clears up a lot of things, thank you very much! I'll get back to it and let you know if I get everything figured out :)